# Why is my searching algorithm in Java not working?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

We just started Java at school and I was wondering why this search algorithm isn't working:
the purpose of the entire code is to store N wine bottles (object) in a cellar (array) and to search for the bottles with the same year and type (red, white, etc..) starting from an input given by the user. I used the same algorithm to search for wine bottles from a specific year and to return them as a StringBuilder and it worked.

```
public StringBuilder StampaTipo(String t) {
    StringBuilder tipo= new StringBuilder(50);
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<this.cantina.length;i++) {
        if(this.cantina[i].getTipo()==t) {
            tipo.append(this.cantina[i].toString());
        }
    }
    return tipo;
}
```

I was expecting to find the search results, this what i'm using in the main:

```
System.out.println("\nInserisci il tipo da cercare: ");
ricercaT=in.next();
System.out.println("\nBottiglie trovate: "+"\n"+c.StampaTipo(ricercaT));
```

"ricercaT" is the String input given by the user to find the bottles based on the type.

This is the output:

```
Insert the type of wine to find: 
red

Bottles found:
```

Comment: `getTipo()==t` - use `equals` to compare objects (strings) not reference equality.  As in `getTipo().equals(t)`.  Also should probably ignore case.

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.